# Seperator with image icon in the middle

Tags: html, css, image, icons, separator

i'm trying to make a separator with an image in the middle. Which is also responsive.

I'm having trouble displaying the icon/image in the middle of the line and in full size. it seems to cut off the top and bottom. could someone take a look at the code?

```
<div class='line-icon'></div>

.line-icon {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('http://www.welzendesign.com/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ster.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.line-icon::before, .line-icon::after {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #837048;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5p8khya/

Comment: it appears to be working on the fiddle?

Comment: No the image isn't displayed in full size also the line is not in the middle of the image :(

Comment: ah.. well you did not state that either of those were a problem in the initial post!

Comment: It looks like you can simply adjust the `padding-top` value say `4px`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I will change edit my question

Comment: Pangloss any ideas how i can get the full image to show it seems to cut off teh top and bottom now

Comment: Set a height to .line-icon make it equal or greater than the image height.

Comment: I could do this but then the line would no longer be in the middle

Comment: Adjust both the height and padding-top values then https://jsfiddle.net/L5p8khya/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you are trying to get. Check the result

```css
.line-icon {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('http://www.welzendesign.com/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ster.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    font-size:0;
    height: 40px;
}
.line-icon::before, .line-icon::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40%;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #837048;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    position:relative;
      top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='line-icon'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Xahed this also works. Why did you use transform code? Is there a reason or just a different way of achieving the result?

Comment: this way you get absolute center position. Whenever i need to make an element vertically center, i use this.

Comment: Can I contact you via e-mail i might have work for you. I saw your freelancer profile.

Comment: Could you send me an e-mail to: t.welzen@4webcom.com

Answer (score 1):

Is think this what you're after? Just give the image a height. Also add a margin-top equal to the half of the image (20px in this case).

```css
.line-icon {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('http://www.welzendesign.com/startransfer/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/ster.png');
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
.line-icon::before, .line-icon::after {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #837048;
    display: inline-block;
    content:'';
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='line-icon'></div>
```

Comment: Thank Mathijs!! this is exactly what i needed!